# New iOS target as an in app purchase

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, ios8

Is it possible technically to provide a 'Today Extension' as an in app purchase?. As far as i can see, soon after you install the main target, the extension target is also getting deployed. I dont see a way to limit that. My idea is to provide one extension for free and other two remaining extensions as in app purchase. Since each extension lives as a seperate target in the xcode, am not sure how to proceed. Any insight will be really helpful

Regards,
Kesava

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because extensions must be delivered with the app and you will need to include all 3 extensions when you build and submit your app + extensions to Apple, I think your best option is to provide all 3, but in the two "premium" extensions, check if the user has made the in-app purchase.  If not, provide an overlay that explains that the extension requires an in-app purchase and provide a button to take them to the app to make the purchase.

You might even be able to request the in-app purchase from within the extension, if that's an experience you think would be good.

Comment: I thought about it. But it would make a bad UX. Also i doubt if apple would allow such invasive behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, I think the only other options would be either: a) provide free, limited functionality in each of the 3 extensions or b) provide a paid version of the app that has all 3 extensions.  I don't think either option is great, but unless apple provides the ability to register and unregister extensions in your app package, I don't know what other option you have.